# Table 'avc.consumptions_message' doesn't exist

Tags: django

When I try to access "message" in the Django admin panel I get the next error:

> Table 'avc.consumptions_message' doesn't exist

The thing is that it is true, the table consumptions_message is not in my database.

this is my model of Message

```
class Message(LogsMixin, models.Model):
    """Definición de modelo para Mensajes"""

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=("Usuario"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(("Fecha y hora del mensaje"), default=now)
    comsumption = models.ForeignKey(Consumption, verbose_name=("Consumo"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.CharField("Contenido del mensaje", max_length=300, null=False, blank=False)
    read = models.BooleanField("Leído por el cliente", default=False)
    deleted = models.BooleanField("Mensaje borrado", null=False, default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        string = self.content
        string = string+"..."

        return string

    class Meta:
        """Meta definición para Mensajes."""

        verbose_name = 'Mensaje'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Mensajes'
```

I have already done "makemigrations" and "migrate" and it doesn't throw any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your app name (where this model is included) is registered in your `INSTALLED_APPS` of your project `settings.py` and if not append your app name as a string to this list and then run management commands (`makemigrations` and `migrate`) to create your tables in database.

Comment: Yeah it is included. The others models are working well and they are in the same app.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was create the database again. I drop the old one and when I used the migrate command everything worked fine.